# Trying to save variable as list of custom parse object (UserRecipe) and print them to the xcode console

Tags: parse-platform, ios9.1, xcode7.1

I'm trying to do just a real simple thing in xcode with the ios parse sdk (1.9.1). Im trying to create a variable that will store all the data I have in my parse custom object called UserRecipe

Here is what my parse set up looks like

[image: Parse Set Up]

Below is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
//import ParseFacebookUtilsV4
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let userRecipe = PFObject(className: "UserRecipe")

        print(userRecipe)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

In my xcode console log this is what I have being returned:

[image: Xcode console log]

It doesnt seem to be returning my 5 recipe objects in the UserRecipe class in parse. can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code just creates a new object locally and logs it to the console.  In order to see the objects stored in the remote data, you'll need to query them.

[Read all about it here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide), but to summarize...

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"UserRecipe")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    if let objects = objects {
      for object in objects {
        print(object["recipeName"])
      }
    }
  } else {
    print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
  }
}
```